# Strange ClassCastException in Android

Tags: android, button, imageview, classcastexception

I get a strange ClassCastException when trying to find a Button in Android.
The ID is definetly connected to Button and no ImageView has the same ID

**Logcat Ouput**

```
12-26 14:10:24.325: E/AndroidRuntime(1307): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 14:10:24.325: E/AndroidRuntime(1307): java.lang.ClassCastException:       android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
12-26 14:10:24.325: E/AndroidRuntime(1307):     at com.appstasy.appprototype.MainActivity.updateUi(MainActivity.java:212)
```

**MainActivity line 212**

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mehr);
```

My layout hast 2500 lines so I will just post the section with the button I´m trying to access
All other layouts do not contain the id "mehr"

**tab1.xml**

```
           <Button
            android:id="@+id/mehr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/favo49"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:onClick="loadMore"
            android:text="GIB MIR MEHR"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:visibility="gone" >
            </Button>
```

Comment: Are you sure that there is no other xml element with the id mehr?

Comment: Did you try to clean / rebuild your project?

Comment: post your imageview declaration

Comment: Yes, I am sure. The find option in Eclipse couldn´t find any other "mehr" in all of my xmls. Cleaning didn´t solve the Problem. There are 50 imageViews, should i post them all? It´s always the same text, except the number of the ID changed for the image Views

Comment: Try to change your Button id and compile the project.

Comment: Closed and reopened my Eclipse and now it works... strange, but thank you guys anyway